# Should I use an anonymous inner class to simulate 'out' parameters in Java?

Tags: java, android, anonymous-inner-class

I'm still a relative newbie when it comes to Java, coming mainly from a C# background.

I was discussing the lack of 'out' parameters in Java methods with a colleague and how to work around this.  He suggested creating a structure/class to hold the various parameters and passing it back.

Sometimes this feels 'wrong' to me - especially if I have a special method that I want to use to return a subset of parameters from a larger class.

So I wondered about using anonymous inline classes instead to achieve this.   Code sample below.

Is this a sensible approach?  Just wondering what the perceived wisdom is on this.

```
public class MyClass {

    Patient myPatient = null;

    // An interface to enable us to return these variables in a single call
    public interface VitalStatsResponse { public void returnStats(int bloodPressure, int heartRate);  }

    public class Patient {

        int bloodPressure = 100;
        int heartRate = 280;
        // Lots of other variables here

        public void calculateVitalStats(VitalStatsResponse response)
        {
            response.returnStats((bloodPressure * 2), (heartRate / 10) ;
        }
    }


    public void doWork()
    {
        // We want the patient's blood pressure and heart rate returned by a single method call, so use an anonymous inline class
        myPatient.calculateVitalStats(new VitalStatsResponse() {
            @Override
            public void returnStats(int bloodPressure, int heartRate) {
                // Handle returned variables here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally I'd use the "class to hold the properties I care about" in C# rather than `out` parameters anyway - if a certain set of properties has a useful meaning, why not have a type for that? Often I find that having done that, the "larger class" can just use that too, and become simpler. For example, a Person class shouldn't have "DateOfBirth, Street1, Street2, Street3, ZipCode, Country"... they should (maybe) have "DateOfBirth, Address". The out parameter approach makes some sense for *private* methods, but I'm not a fan for public ones.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the simple solution of creating a VitalStats object. If you need the VitalStatus of a patient, then VitalStats is a concept in your application that can be represented as an Object.

```
public class VitalStatus {

    final int bloodPressure;
    final int heartRate;

    public VitalStats(int bloodPressure, int heartRate) {
        this.bloodPressure = bloodPressure;
        this.heartRate = heartRate;
    }
}

public class Patient {

    int bloodPressure = 100;
    int heartRate = 280;
    // Other variables

    public VitalStatus getVitalStatus() {
        return new VitalStats(bloodPressured * 2, heartRate / 2);
    }
}
```

Out params is a procedural solution for return times. Java primarily fits the Object Oriented paradigm of programming and as such don't be afraid to make objects. This fits with the S in [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) if your class is doing a lot of complex things see if you can break it down into smaller more manageable pieces.

Comment: Interesting.  But it's so much more code than my suggestion!  So why is this better?

Comment: @CarlosP I updated the answer to include a little more information. It is not much more code but the code is easier to read IMO. In OOP it often better to have many small classes that are easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I would also use "class to hold the parameters" over "inline anonymous inner class"

```
public class MyClass implements VitalStatsResponse{

Patient myPatient = null;
private ArrayList<VitalStatsResponse> response;


void MyClass(ArrayList<VitalStatsResponse> response) {

    this.response = response;
}


public class Patient {

    int bloodPressure = 100;
    int heartRate = 280;
    // Lots of other variables here

    public void calculateVitalStats()
    {
    for(int i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            // call returnStats method of every registered callback
            response.get(i).returnStats((bloodPressure * 2), (heartRate / 10) ;
        }
    }
}

// any client can register/unregister callback via these methods
void registerResponse(VitalStatsResponse response) {
    this.response.add(response);
}

void unRegisterResponse(VitalStatsResponse response) {
    this.response.remove(response);
}

public void doWork()
{
    // We want the patient's blood pressure and heart rate returned by a single method call, so use an anonymous inline class
    myPatient.calculateVitalStats();
}

public void returnStats(int bloodPressure, int heartRate) {

// implement the body according to this class requirement
}
}
```